# Access function defined in _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, view, razor

In an ASP.MVC application, I have a function defined in my **_ViewStart.cshtml** like this:

```
@functions
{
    public void Foo()
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

When I try to use this function in of my views, I get an exception saying that :
*The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current context*
I thought that all what I define in _ViewStart.cshtml is accessible to all my views that define it as layout.

I am missing something here ...
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place reusable functions them inside Razor views of the special `App_Code` folder.

For example inside `~/App_Code/Foo.cshtml` you could declare a `Bar` function:

```
@functions {
    public static void Bar() {

    }
}
```

that will be accessible from any Razor view:

```
@{Foo.Bar();}
```

Also notice that the function must be declared as **static**.

Comment: I cannot access there any MVC Html. helpers
If do UrlHelp.Action I get an error message

Comment: That's normal, you will have to pass it as argument: `public static void Bar(HtmlHelper html) { ... }`. And then call `@{Foo.Bar(Html);}`.

Comment: I don't understand what behind all this and  why I can't use _ViewStart.schtml. Your solution is however working. Thanks